# MySQL Query for reversed data

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with MySQL query. I have datas look like this :

```
transaction_type | currency_from | currency_to |
------------------------------------------------
swap             | USD           | IDR         |
swap             | IDR           | USD         |
forward          | GBP           | USD         |
forward          | USD           | GBP         |
forward          | JPY           | EUR         |
forward          | EUR           | JPY         |
spot             | USD           | EUR         |
spot             | EUR           | USD         |
```

Is it possible to have output look like this :

```
transaction_type | currency_from | currency_to |
------------------------------------------------
swap             | USD           | IDR         |
forward          | GBP           | USD         |
forward          | JPY           | EUR         |
spot             | USD           | EUR         |
```

As seen above, every transactions will have reversed transactions, swap USD-IDR, will also have swap IDR-USD forward GBP-USD will also have forward USD-GBP, so do the spot. I have tried many ways, but still not success. Anyone can help ? Thanks before..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do as the following

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM tblTransaction AS t1 INNER JOIN tblTransaction AS t2
ON (
    t1.transaction_type = t2.transaction_type AND 
    t1.currency_from = t2.currency_to AND
    t1.currency_to = t2.currency_from AND
    t1.currency_from > t2.currency_from
)
```